# XSLT get totals from one HTML table into another HTML table

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML which needs to be transformed using XSLT 1. The xml is immutable, I cannot create new elements or attributes.

I’ve created a key on the Cell__GroupingName and used Meunchian grouping to sort each Cell into Blocks. I’ve iterated through each cell in each block and listed the people that are in each cell.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?> 
    <DATASETLIST xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
     <DATASET entity="CELL">
        <ROW>
            <Cell__Id>1010025012000000031980475</Cell__Id>
            <Cell__Name>A Block</Cell__Name>
            <Cell__Occupancy>36</Cell__Occupancy>
            <Cell__OccupancyCount>1</Cell__OccupancyCount>
            <Cell__GroupingName>A</Cell__GroupingName>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <Cell__Id>1010025012000000031980476</Cell__Id>
            <Cell__Name >EB.101 Handicap</Cell__Name>
            <Cell__Occupancy>1</Cell__Occupancy>
            <Cell__OccupancyCount>0</Cell__OccupancyCount>
            <Cell__GroupingName>B</Cell__GroupingName>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <Cell__Id>1010025012000000031980477</Cell__Id>
            <Cell__Name>EB.102</Cell__Name>
            <Cell__Occupancy>1</Cell__Occupancy>
            <Cell__OccupancyCount>0</Cell__OccupancyCount>
            <Cell__GroupingName>B</Cell__GroupingName>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <Cell__Id>1010025012000000032172223</Cell__Id>
            <Cell__Name>Ec.101</Cell__Name>
            <Cell__Occupancy>1</Cell__Occupancy>
            <Cell__OccupancyCount>1</Cell__OccupancyCount>
            <Cell__GroupingName>B</Cell__GroupingName>
        </ROW>
    </DATASET>
        <DATASET entity="EVENT;JT">
        <ROW>
            <EVENT__Id>162325012000000046845209</EVENT__Id>
            <EVENT__GPPCCustodyTypeG>Warrant - Felony</EVENT__GPPCCustodyTypeG>
            <EVENT__WhiteboardIndicatorsG>Epileptic</EVENT__WhiteboardIndicatorsG>
            <EVENT__LabelCell>EC.101</EVENT__LabelCell>
            <JT__Cell_ID />
            <JT__Remarks/> 
            <DATASET entity="CHARGE">
                <ROW>
                    <CHARGE__SectionMergedNS>594(a)pc</CHARGE__SectionMergedNS>
                </ROW>
            </DATASET>
            <DATASET entity="P">
                <ROW>
                    <P__SurnameG>Person</P__SurnameG>
                    <P__Given1>one</P__Given1>
                </ROW>
            </DATASET>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <EVENT__Id>162325012000000046937292</EVENT__Id>
            <EVENT__GPPCCustodyTypeG>Felony</EVENT__GPPCCustodyTypeG>
            <EVENT__WhiteboardIndicatorsG/>
            <EVENT__LabelCell>A Block</EVENT__LabelCell>
            <JT__Cell_ID>1010025012000000031980475</JT__Cell_ID>
            <JT__Remarks />

            <DATASET entity="CHARGE">
                <ROW>
                    <CHARGE__SectionMergedNS>594(a)pc</CHARGE__SectionMergedNS>
                </ROW>
            </DATASET>
            <DATASET entity="P">
                <ROW>
                    <P__SurnameG>Person2</P__SurnameG>
                    <P__Given1>Two</P__Given1>
                </ROW>
            </DATASET>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <EVENT__Id>162325012000000046763873</EVENT__Id>
            <EVENT__GPPCCustodyTypeG>Misdemeanor</EVENT__GPPCCustodyTypeG>
            <EVENT__WhiteboardIndicatorsG>High blood pressure</EVENT__WhiteboardIndicatorsG>
            <EVENT__LabelCell>EB.103</EVENT__LabelCell>
            <JT__Cell_ID>1010025012000000032172223</JT__Cell_ID>
            <JT__Remarks/>

            <DATASET entity="CHARGE">
               <ROW>                    
                  <CHARGE__SectionMergedNS>11377(a)hs</CHARGE__SectionMergedNS>
                </ROW>
            </DATASET>
            <DATASET entity="P">
                <ROW>
                    <P__SurnameG>PERSON3</P__SurnameG>
                    <P__Given1>THREE</P__Given1>
                </ROW>-                
            </DATASET>
        </ROW>
    </DATASET>
</DATASETLIST>
```

What I’m trying to do now is create a separate table (the bottom table in the code) that calculates the amount of felonies, misdemeanor and space available for each cell block. Preferably without having to iterate through the loop again.

```
    <xsl:key name="cells-by-blocks" match="//*[@entity='CELL']/ROW" 
    use="Cell__GroupingName" />
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[@entity='CELL']/ROW[count(. | key('cells-by- 
     blocks',Cell__GroupingName)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:variable name="blocks" select="key('cells-by-blocks', 
    Cell__GroupingName)" /> 
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Cell</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Charge</th>
            <th>Level</th> (felony or misd)
            <th>Remarks</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>                                          
            <xsl:for-each select="$blocks">
              <xsl:for-each select="//*[JT__Cell_ID = current()/Cell__Id]">                                                             
                <tr>
                    <th class="cell-num">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains(EVENT__LabelCell, 'Block')">
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                               <xsl:value-of select="EVENT__LabelCell" />
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>                                                               
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/DATASET/ROW/P__SurnameG"/>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/DATASET/ROW/P__Given1"/>
                    </td>                 
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/DATASET/ROW/CHARGE__SectionMergedNS" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="EVENT__GPPCCustodyTypeG"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="notes">
                        <xsl:value-of select="EVENT__WhiteboardIndicatorsG" />
                        <xsl:if test=" not(JT__Remarks = '') ">
                            <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="JT__Remarks" /> 
                        </xsl:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>                                                               
            </xsl:for-each>                                                                 
        </xsl:for-each>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="totals" class="col-md-6 table-bordered totals-table">                                                    
    <tr>
        <h4>Count Breakdown:</h4>
      </tr>                                                     
            <tr>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Felony</th>
                <th>Misdemeanor</th>
                <th>Cells Available</th>
            </tr>                                                   
            <tr >
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select= How many bodies in this cell block/>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <xsl:value-of select= How many felonies in this block/> 
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pagebreak"></div>
   </div>                                  
  </xsl:for-each>
```

If I try to pass parameters into a template, my variables are out of scope because I’m outside the for-each loops. I’ve tried by counting the HTML elements, but I’m guessing since the HTML is wrapped in CDATA, it cannot be picked up. 
I’m sure there is a simple solution for this, but I just can’t seem to see it.

Comment: If the variable `blocks` represents a block you would simply need to use it and select the elements representing "bodies" or "felonies" e.g. `count($blocks//body)`. I am not sure which elements in that input represent a "body". If the information is not part of the `$blocks` variable but elsewhere in the document then you need to explain how to select/reference it, I am afraid that is not obvious to me from the sample XML.

Comment: If the `//*[JT__Cell_ID = current()/Cell__Id]` is a hint then I guess you need another key for the elements you want `match="*"` and `use="JT__Cell_ID"` and then use that key e.g. `count(key('key-name', $blocks/Cell__Id)//body)`. Again "body" is an example of an element to select, I have not understood which element represents a "body".

Comment: Sorry for being unclear... a "body" in this case is a person in a cell which would be represented by  `DATASET[@entity='EVENT;JT']/ROW/JT__Cell_ID`.  $blocks only holds the cell data, not the arrestee data, so I will try to create another key like you suggested.  Thanks.